# Typescript: Type is not assignable to conditional type

Tags: typescript

I have a function which queries my database, and based on whether we are pulling "saved" data or "unsaved" data will change the output. I am wanting to keep this condensed into one function and so am working with Conditional Types to let Typescript know that the response of the function will change based on the type.

If saved, the function should return an array of ProductType (a custom type I have made), otherwise it should return an array of strings.

```
type ProductType = {
    title: string;
    price: number;
};

type QueryResponse<T> = T extends 'unsaved'
    ? ProductType[]
    : T extends 'saved'
    ? string[]
    : never;

export async function queryDb<T extends 'saved' | 'unsaved'>(
    type: T,
): Promise<QueryResponse<T>> {
    // Get correct DB URL based on type input.
    let dbUrl: string;
    if (type === 'saved') {
        dbUrl = 'DATABASEURL/saved';
    } else {
        dbUrl = 'DATABASEURL/unsaved';
    }

    // Fetch data from the database.
    const r = await fetch(dbUrl);
    const dbResult = JSON.parse(await r.json());

    // Structure the data correctly to be in line with the types, then return.
    if (type === 'saved') {
        let response: string[] = dbResult.data;
        return response;
    } else {
        let response: ProductExample[] = dbResult.data;
        return response;
    }
}
```

I get an error under both return statements saying: `Type 'ProductType[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryResponse<T>'.`, and `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryResponse<T>'.` respectively.

Comment: How does `type` relate to `dbResult.data`? it just seems like you are checking one thing, and doing something else

Comment: What if you just did `return dbResult.data` inside the function?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Any values or types you use should be defined, and any code necessary to demonstrate should be present. Right now it's not clear what `dbResult` is or how it has to do with `type`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have updated to include a better example, apologies for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, while your conditional type `QueryResponse<T>` correctly infers the return type from `T`, TypeScript is not able to leverage your `type === 'saved'` condition as a type guard:

```
    // Structure the data correctly to be in line with the types, then return.
    if (type === 'saved') {
        let response: string[] = dbResult.data;
        type // type is NOT narrowed down to "saved" type
        //^? (parameter) type: T extends "saved" | "unsaved"
        return response; // Error: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryResponse<T>'.
    } else {
        let response: ProductType[] = dbResult.data;
        type
        //^? (parameter) type: T extends "saved" | "unsaved"
        return response; // Error: Type 'ProductType[]' is not assignable to type 'QueryResponse<T>'.
    }
```

As suggested by smac89 in the question comments, you could just skip the block that tries to type the return, since it is already specified by your explicit return type:

```
export async function queryDb0<T extends 'saved' | 'unsaved'>(
    type: T,
): Promise<QueryResponse<T>> {
    // Etc

    // We may even skip typing the return here, it is already done in the explicit return type
    return dbResult.data;
}
```

---

In your case, you could even avoid the conditional type, by simply using a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead:

```
export async function queryDb2(type: 'saved'): Promise<string[]>
export async function queryDb2(type: 'unsaved'): Promise<ProductType[]>
export async function queryDb2(type: 'saved' | 'unsaved'): Promise<string[] | ProductType[]> {
    // Etc.

    // We may even skip typing the return here, it is already done in the overloads
    return dbResult.data;
}
```

Let's check its usage:

```
const s = queryDb2('saved');
//    ^? const s: Promise<string[]>

const u = queryDb2('unsaved');
//    ^? const u: Promise<ProductType[]>

const o2 = queryDb2('other'); // Error: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, [...] Argument of type '"other"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"saved"'. Overload 2 of 2, [...] Argument of type '"other"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"unsaved"'.
```

Looks good!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwAq5oF4oDeAUFKVMAJbAA2EAXFAM7BwUB2A5gNwllitp6UNigC2AIwhweAXx5FQkKAEUUUkACUIjMAjaMIAHkwA+KPkxQIAD2AQ2SRlADkKfQEMAbhCTPepAH5YRFQMbEgAbQBdfygGSxs7BydnRi8fPzIoIOZWTmjYhjYIb2kiIhtdOGAod0YQNjQoADM3DAo9KABHNTgQABFxYytbe0cXNO9fKAAfFzdJjJMACljFIUwAGiIASgZ4BFEKA0NVdS0dPRPTM2IsgHp7qABxCBq0BDg4CAwofoAhKAAVQ0ABkoOI6j4oJ11lB2GAUMAAHSxWg1JDiIFwagMXLsbixCjNKDLOG4CkTdK+HaEWJZTHY6jmFz9ACCmDZ-zZAGUAKIg0H3Ra+HhZGRWagGOlZBlYnEs5zsznc-mC+4LanOMVkGTlB5PABibzQAAsoEh3MB3C1EKJyKboJbrZCDKish99DU4Cz3AB3dxUFom03LRk4nY60ie5gW8QXFDUGr4ABSPIA8gA5ZFgdxwAzLf2B73IgBWjD0yx2kf1ZEeUB5LHQwBQ3wdTqtNo+Xx+NBA5AQEOg7Cg1HY0D9VHNwEd5BwjE27bYUG+LbgbHdZGJpPJlNSWtpd1lpHRK+0un0Qnx+SiLMxCaTyOd7ijsvW9Lr9wAegEP6RV62y7fJcl5cFA9Z8l8nzxDgEwsAS0TOPCThsAgNR1IwFAcGw7jiLQA5zkozhnH0FwXtcJjOJupAShAUrQEex6nsB5FCAcoRYDg0R3vG2iJiiz6vlk77HqQjw-n+Z5rkB55XBAYEQVBcAwUR7HNuEECIchwhobUjCYdhuH4cAg5wsRvSaLJl7GJR1FQHqeoVNYVTofUjQtG0lCdD06iDAADMMiRjCkIpIXMrgeFMzgrGsODxNsezBIcxxGCRlkgRRtyxPWrzvJ83y-ACwJghCUJIDCy5wgiSJ2ae4a4kw8GcK+25krBFL4PuUWHpJ9WKsqXK8gKYLClqr60fRMqiX1nUDaqw1CpqUXjbWYlGiGFqdrahztptLpQnZMber6AZBs0IZhvK1A1h6VwYrxjD8SyaZZjmeYFkWQZwGWFZsFWNbZU8ADq0CiO4-YlPYTAANYUGAhEErtAHrlAjrfIuQbHLU1DfO4SD9kgejDpVs6VGOaBfW8gGERAsTI8u958Y+glEI5lSfK5DRNK0jRecuPl9IMABMbWQAwXUZIlBxHCc14cNEJhOS5elcx5vMdPzFnC6LQgRaFUt2ilhhqWEXFRIr7PVCr7k8+03la+IIvrOLoWzPMkWS-shuy018u3nMJucZE5tTWtLxvFA3YFTURWCqVBjlbCsHVSiaIR-VeK+y1JI6+Ye766HsozayHKDWqI2heNkrSoxRdXf1pfzeqS0ZCtgNQMawBmntNrNHau3Pq6ECHXdK4ncWwZd6G9U3WQR1xg+yZQC92a5vmECFqdJblpW1byAaUAg1AYMQ94y6MLD8OKIjM7QPTqNSBAGM1Fj7g4xAeME0T8Ik9ACClNQBAeNGB0ypijRmj1madlkOUeeTh8ACwGI7ZYEsaQ8HrGQCSRB54oBZIg7WesDzoKeJg382DR4ICFngh2ItnBoTRs4SM4EniQUQMpKAmZBz-ykIAvGx8rRmm0A6LGaA37UGRFAdMACgHlQAIwwhJELRcERkSqNvGyOAHAxD2BqAgEkZkABE9CpAGKQljVCrkDI4TwtAEyUA17uFEG8KQCiaYuAMSKUxEipE8JkVAKhej-HKNUcidRmjtFsF0fo2CzgjG3zgKY7SFi9JWKMrYwcDinF2B9IEwxLckBeKIEAA)